# ratio goes beyond 100%

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure " realiseret ratios %". It calculates the allocation of cost in % but when I filter out some variables like 105 in left column then it recalculates the ratio and i goes beyond 100%. the ratio market with red must never surpass 100%. picture 1 is with no filter(including 105) and picture 2 is with filter(excluding 105)

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

The code for the measure is:

```
realiseret ratios %:= Var Income = 
     CALCULATE(
         [Project Cost Amount],
        
             All(Art),Art[Type]= "I" 
     )
Var Expense = 
     CALCULATE(
         ABS([Project Cost Amount])     )
return  Divide(If(ISBLANK(Expense), Blank(), Expense) , Income,Blank())
```

Art type "I" is all our revenue. and "199 omsætning" is the revenue in left column

Comment: Can you please improve the question, and also add some detalis about the model, some sample data and the actual code for the measure "reasalieret ratios %" ?